# Does a previous AFSP approval get invalidated when making a new training request?

Tags: general-aviation, flight-training, usa, tsa

If I've already been approved, and started training in one school and then create a training request to switch to another school, does the previous approval expire?

In other words, can I be simultaneously approved on two different schools?

I'm considering transferring temporarily to continue flying in a different region, but would like to have the option to return to my original school without yet another training request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple requests open at the same time. This is from [the AFSP Candidate Application Guide](https://www.flightschoolcandidates.gov/afsp2/common_servlet/help.html?clean=1&nav=guide#APPCORE) (step 7):

> It is possible for a Candidate to have several active training requests at a given time. These requests may be for the same or different flight training providers. Each training request form will be processed separately; AFSP approval is valid only for the Provider listed in the application.

Comment: I was actually asking specifically about having an approved status on more than one request, which is slightly different than having multiple requests merely open at the same time. Are you sure a previously approved request doesn't get deleted or become invalid when a new one gets approved?

Comment: @GJ Yes, that's what the second sentence is saying: each application is handled independently. I've had two open myself in the past, some 'good' news is that you only have to submit your fingerprints once and they can use them for all future applications.